# Go through sub tags of IsoMsg and get values for jPOS

Tags: jpos

I have a jPOS project and I want to loop through sub tags of a field to get it's values. I have the following code and I don't know if it does the job:

```java
    Map<String, String> subTagMap = new HashMap<>();
    ISOMsg champ11 = (ISOMsg)isoMsg.getComponent(11);
    int i = 1;
    while(i < 15) {
        if (champ11  != null) {
            ISOTaggedField subtTag = findTag(champ11, (i < 10) ? "0" + i : String.valueOf(i));
            if (subtTag != null) {
                LOGGER.debug("Champ11x" + i +"trouvé");
                subTagMap.put(subtTag.getTag(), subtTag.getValue().toString());
            }
        }
i++;
    }
    return subTagMap;
}


private ISOTaggedField findTag(ISOComponent component, String tagName) {
        if (component instanceof ISOTaggedField) {
            component = ((ISOTaggedField) component).getDelegate();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<Integer, Object> children = component.getChildren();

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Object> entry : children.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue() instanceof ISOTaggedField) {
                ISOTaggedField tag = (ISOTaggedField) entry.getValue();

                if (tag.getTag().equals(tagName)) {
                    return tag;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to say since you didn't share your `findTag` code

Comment: also I don't see where you increment i

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```java
Map<String, String> subTagMap=new HashMap<>();
ISOMsg champ11 = (ISOMsg) isoMsg.getComponent(119);

if (champ != null) { 
    for (Object v : champ.getChildren().values()) {
        if (!(v instanceof ISOTaggedField)) continue;
        ISOTaggedField subTag = (ISOTaggedField) v;
        subTagMap.put(subTag.getTag(), (String)subTag.getValue());
    }
}
return subTagMap;
```

Comment: HelloAndres ,thanks for the reeponse , i updated my code ,u can check it ,but my question is do ISOTaggedField containes the tag value ,and the tag content value?thanks

Comment: yes it does, but it's simpler to iterate over the values, you don't need the position, this answer lacks the check if the component v is instance of ISOTaggedField. I'll update when in the PC. But has meny less lines of code. And only has one level of iteration